# NFS for Ubuntu host server 20.04

Tags: nfs

I am planning to follow this manual for setting up my NFS server:
https://quidsup.net/tutorials/?p=nfs

I just don't know how outdated it is and what to modify if my local address is:

```
192.162.1.100
```

And the RAID which I want share is mounted on: `/mnt/rdisk`

Edit: I have webmin.

Edit2: It is a local network and I don't plan using the internet.

Edit3: Based on the posted tutorial the command in the config file can be this:

```
/mnt/rdisk  192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,root_squash,subtree_check)
```

Comment: You are not telling what your network setup is, but a good place to start would be [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)

Comment: @Sebastian It is a local network.

Comment: Then the link I gave you should be fine. I used it to set up NFS between a 18.04 and a 20.04 machine on my local network just recently.

Comment: @Sebastian OK, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sebastian This truly works:

```
/mnt/rdisk  192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,root_squash,subtree_check)
```